# Php : Curl unwanted output

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Below Curl Code

```
<?php
     $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/events';
     $fields = array(
                      'access_token' => $token,
                      'name' => 'Event name',
                      'description' => 'The Description ',
                      'start_time' => '2013-03-02'
                    ); 

     foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 

     {
          $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
     }
          rtrim($fields_string, '&');

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
?>
```

In Above Code , I did not use echo $result , But its returning output as `{"id":"209557021119579"}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

for return data instead of echoing data

Answer (score 0):

you should use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```